# How to count the frequency of a record based on condition in another column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({
   ...:     'donorID':[101,101,101,102,103,101,101,102,103],
   ...:     'recipientID':[11,11,21,21,31,11,21,31,31],
   ...:     'amount':[100,200,500,200,200,300,200,200,100],
   ...:     'year':[2014,2014,2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015]
   ...: })

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   amount  donorID  recipientID  year
0     100      101           11  2014
1     200      101           11  2014
2     500      101           21  2014
3     200      102           21  2014
4     200      103           31  2014
5     300      101           11  2015
6     200      101           21  2015
7     200      102           31  2015
8     100      103           31  2015
```

I'd like to count the number of donor-recipient pairs by donor (donations made by the same donor to the same recipient in n years, where n could be any number and it doesn't have to be consecutive, but I use 2 here to keep things simple). In this case, donor 101 donated to recipient 11 and 21 in 2014 as well as in 2015, the count for 101 is 2. The number for 102 is 0, and for 103 is 1. The result table would look like this:

```
   donorID  num_donation_2_years
0      101                     2
1      102                     0
2      103                     1
```

I've tried to use groupby and pivot_table but didn't manage to get the right answer. Any suggestion in pandas would be appreciated? Thanks!

Comment: It has to be consecutive, right?

Comment: yes, but now I think about it, it'd be more interesting to also have a condition where it doesn't have to be, as long as the pair appears in different years. I'll edit the question. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
df1=df.groupby('donorID').apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x.recipientID).year.nunique().gt(1).sum())
df1
Out[102]: 
donorID
101    2
102    0
103    1
dtype: int64
```

To get the dataframe

```
df1.to_frame('num_donation_2_years').reset_index()
Out[104]: 
   donorID  num_donation_2_years
0      101                     2
1      102                     0
2      103                     1
```

---

**As Dark mention do not using `apply`**

This is the update

```
df1=df.groupby(['donorID','recipientID']).year.nunique().gt(1).sum(level=0)
df1
Out[109]: 
donorID
101    2.0
102    0.0
103    1.0
Name: year, dtype: float64

df1.to_frame('num_donation_2_years').reset_index()
Out[104]: 
   donorID  num_donation_2_years
0      101                     2
1      102                     0
2      103                     1
```

Comment: I wanted to add my solution as a comment. Since it was huge I posted an answer. If you want you can add it to your answer. I will delete mine.

Comment: @Dark that is ok ,i just get used to use one line

Comment: you can make that to one line too :). Better to avoid nested groupby using apply.

Comment: @Dark yeas , you are right , I updated , look better now : -) thanks

Comment: @Dark you do not need delete it man , since we are not the same :-)

Comment: I added your `nunique()` method to my method. Learn from you again!

Comment: @Tai yw ~ :-)  happy coding

Comment: Thanks for this elegant solution! I see that by changing gt() I get stats for different years, and changing sum() levels for different variable counts like unique recipient counts etc. This really saved me at least hours of work :)

Comment: @alys yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 3):

An improvement to @Wen's solution, avoiding `apply` for more speed i.e

```
one = df.groupby(['donorID','recipientID'])['year'].nunique().gt(1)

two = one.groupby(level=0).sum().to_frame('no_of_donations_2_years').reset_index()

    donorID  no_of_donations_2_years
0      101                      2.0
1      102                      0.0
2      103                      1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_new = df.groupby(["donorID", "recipientID"])["year"].nunique().reset_index(name="year_count")
df_for_query = df_new.groupby(["donorID", "year_count"]).size().reset_index(name='numb_recipient')

    donorID year_count  numb_recipient
 0  101      2            2
 1  102      1            2
 2  103      2            1
```

The third column is how many patients that fit the year condition. The line 0 says donor `101` has 2 patients that he/she donates in exactly two years. This is not exactly your output, but you can query it easily from this df.

If you want to find that the number of patients a donor donates for some number of year, say 2, run

```
df_for_query.query("year_count == 2")

        donorID     year_count  numb_recipient
    0    101         2              2
    2    103         2              1
```

Thanks for Wen's inspiration for using `nunique`!

Comment: better check your out put :-)

Comment: @Wen Checking now. Thanks! I am calculating different things from yours. I think that's why the output is different.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works (explanation as comments) (ol for outlist):

```
# count frequency of donor-recipient combination
ol = pd.value_counts(df.apply(lambda x: str(x.donorID)+str(x.recipientID), axis=1)) 
ol = ol[ol>=2]                                  # choose only those >= 2
ol.index = list(map(lambda x: x[:3], ol.index)) # get donorID name again 
print(pd.value_counts(ol.index))                # print desired frequency
```

Output:

```
101    2
103    1
dtype: int64
```